# Are there performance benefits in storing HTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

We are using an Oracle product with a built-in form designer. This form designer allows the user to create a form definition, basically a collection of sections with sections containing lines. This generates a schema which is then converted using XSLT into HTML.

Recently Oracle changed this XSLT to so that the HTML for each section is stored in javascript arrays so that it can be hidden/shown.

Example:

```
 section_html['registrationDetails'] = 

    '<table role="presentation" oraMdLabel="EMPTY_SUMMARY" width="100%">'+ 
        '<tbody name="nonRepeatingSchedule">'+  
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+ 
                   '<div c1GroupType="schedule" name="addDeleteControls" nowrap>'+ 
                        '<table role="presentation" oraMdLabel="EMPTY_SUMMARY">'+
                            '<tr>'+
                                '<td class="oraSectionHeader" width="100%">'+

                                    '<span tabIndex="5" name="nonRepeatingHeader" oraMdLabel="CM_REG_DETAILS_LBL"></span>'+
                                '</td>'+
                                '<td class="oraSectionHeader">'+
                                   '<img tabIndex="5" src="images/collapse.gif" onkeypress="toggleHeaderDivInc(this, '+'registrationDetailsHeader'+');" onclick="toggleHeaderDivInc(this, '+'registrationDetailsHeader'+');" width="10" height="9" oraMdLabel="C1_FORM_HEADER_COLLAPSE" id="mainInfoImg">'+
                                '</td>'+
                            '</tr>'+
                        '</table>'+
                   '</div>'+
               '</td>'+
            '</tr>'+
```

This makes it difficult to read, edit and customize! Hiding and showing sections are not really difficult otherwise.

Forms tend to have anything from between 30 to 200 lines with maybe 15 sections max.

Are there real performance advantages to doing it this way? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I wouldn't know what the performance gain could be. Using JavaScript means that the JavaScript needs to be loaded and executing, which is a lot more work than having a form displayed in HTML. (And possibly toggled with a one-line JS snippet.)

Comment: That is my feeling as well. I am not a javascript expert. But I cannot understand why they made the change. They have not documented their reasoning.

Comment: Maybe they are planning on integrating their scripts with something like node.js? Is there a way for you to contact them? Try to do that!

Comment: I have to log a service request that can take more than a month to be answered. They are using some jquery functionality. Thanks for your help.